# Creating admin menu Resource ID issue

Tags: magento-2.2.5

while creating admin menu i am getting this error .
attribute 'resource': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'M_Again::menucontroller' is not accepted by the pattern.

**etc/acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="M_Again::menucontroller" title="magain" translate="title" sortOrder="900"/>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**etc/adminhtml/menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="M_Again::again" title="magain" module="M_Again" translate="title" resource="M_Again::menucontroller" sortOrder="100" action="magain" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

The resource id given in acl.xml is wrong i think explain please what it should be . thanks

Comment: please tell me what your module name and vendor name of this module?

Comment: vendor name M and module name Again... so module name becomes M_Again

Comment: Please changes  to  `M_Again::menucontroller`  to  `M_Again::menu_again` on both two files and  clear the session and flush the cache  and see what happen?

Comment: still same issue ...

Comment: I guess that you have issue with vendor Name. Change to other name

Comment: oh yes you are right ... but i dont understand why name cause this issue ? it was M .. i changed it to Menu and everything is ok ... weird

Comment: facet  mean short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**facet**  mean short and as per as your comment your module is **M**.

You have to changes to it. Then you have to change to other respective files.

Comment: yes i have changed the module name from M to something else and it is working . thanks amit bera